# How to split the denominator of a fraction into another fraction plus the rest of the denominator?

Tags: fractions, partial-fractions

I know the title is a badly formulated, but I have an example, that should show my Problem better:

${y^2\over(2c+2)} = {y^2\over 2c} * x$

Through Brute-Force I found out that x should for example be: $x ={1\over(c+1)*c^{-1}}$

What I want to know is, how (with which strategy) I can solve an equation like this properly?

Comment: You need $x = {2c\over2c+2} = {1\over 1 + {1\over c}}$

Comment: Could you please explain why?

Comment: Simply solve for $x$ (multiply the equation by $2c\over y^2$)